# A thread doesnt respond while app proccessing

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

i have a c# Win Forms application i wrote and it has two threads -the main thread(the GUI) and a thread that is rensposible for responding to a server every x seconds (heartbeat).
but when i run some code on the main thread(removing tabs,disposing things) the gui gets unresponsive and the thread isnt sending the heartbeats- what am i doing wrong?
thanks :)

the thread is created like this:

```
thrMessaging = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ReceiveMessages)); 
thrMessaging.Start();
```

and is actually a thread that is responsible for all messaging getting from ther server -it goes something like this:

```
private void ReceiveMessages()
    {
        // Receive the response from the server
        srReceiver = new StreamReader(tcpServer.GetStream());
        while (Connected)
        {

            // Show the messages in the log TextBox
            //this.Invoke(new UpdateLogCallback(this.UpdateLog), new object[] { srReceiver.ReadLine() });
            try
            {
                String con = srReceiver.ReadLine();
                string StringMessage = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(con, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
                //MessageBox.Show("MESSAGE TRANSLATED:" + StringMessage);
                processMessage(StringMessage);
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {

                connectionTerminated();

            }

        }
    }
```

and since i need the proceesMessage function sometimes to preform some UI tasks it goes like this:

```
private void processMessage(string p)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
            {
                lastMessage = DateTime.Now;
                //MessageBox.Show(p);
                if (p == "AREYOUALIVE")
                {
                    SendMessage("ye");
                }
                else if
                 ......
        }));

        }
    }
```

so the thread should always respond(each x seconds ) to a message from the server asking if he is alive-what doesnt happen while he is proccesing.

Comment: Could you show us what you're doing? The description itself doesn't give away any clues to why it isn't working.

Comment: Please show us some example code - eg how you setup your thread, and and does your thread code do anything that then updates the UI if so, how you've done that.

Comment: There is not enough information to understand your problem. Please share code. How background threads start? Do you use System.Threading.Timer or some other timer? Does background thread has synchronizations with UI thread?

Comment: Does second thread sleeps or is always active?
Can you provide a sample of your implementation?

Comment: @c.EVenhuis @BugFinder @Disposer @Niraj Doshi @Marco added explanation and exmaple.

Comment: @Blue Gene, What .NET version are you using?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Control.BeginInvoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke.aspx) (non blocking) (check link) rather than `Control.Invoke` (blocking).

http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/threads/winforms.shtml

As far I remember, both methods pass a Windows message to the UI queue, `Invoke` sends it using **SEND**, that blocks till a result is obtained, and `BeginInvoke` uses **POST**, that returns inmediately.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem could be this: when you call **Invoke**, GUI update is made by main thread (the GUI one)... so if your main thread is busy in doing something else (deleting controls for example) cannot process this task immediately, locking execution...

Comment: i tryed to get the if out of the invoke-it still doesnt help.

Comment: @Blue Gene: what about changing thrMessaging priority, using for example AboveNormal?
A silly question: tasks you're doing on main form can't be done in a different thread to leave GUI free to dispatch messages?

Comment: I will try that-good idea, and no-tasks that uses the gui can not be done on a diffrent thread without invoking-and if i invoke then it just the same like doing it on the same thread.

Comment: @Blue Gene: if you "remove temporarily" secondary thread, GUI still feeezes while updating controls?
If so, you should try to reduce operations or try to change UI...

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple, it's occurs in case you make marshaling to UI thread by

```
Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate...
```

I can suggest you to make a Queue with messages from server and process this queue in another thread by timer for about 2 or 3 seconds, it will work much faster and background thread that process messages from server never hangs.

The main idea is to update UI not so often as it is done now.

Comment: unfortently i cant process the messages only 2-3 seconds because this is real-time application,and anyway it wont work-the problem is that the thread isn`t excuting at all why the GUI is busy doing that function that takes him some time.